# I am expecting javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException in junit and also throwing same exception from rest api but getting RunTimeException

Tags: spring-boot, junit, automation, junit5, assertion

Exception is not matching in junit test

`Unexpected exception type thrown ==> expected: <javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException> but was: <java.lang.RuntimeException>`

I am trying to run junit and expecting javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException from rest end point but getting ava.lang.RuntimeException

Comment: Paste your program and the test here, else we can't help you.